# Why after write command ls I can't see real folders?

Tags: command-line, ssh, filesystem, home-directory

After user comments, I am going to edit this question trying to be accurate, even when [pLumo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/plumo) gave the correct answer (thanks a lot!)

I open the terminal, to connect my remote server as root user:

```
shh root@myip
```

inside my server as a root user:

```
[root@servidor ~]
```

If type `ls` I get some files BUT I cannot see any folder as `/home`.

When I type `/home`, actually I access to `/home` directory so I can do `ls` and see everything inside this directory.

The question was, why from `[root@servidor ~]` I couldn't see everything in server?

If I do that, but in my laptop, when I run terminal I can see many folders, but like server case, If I do cd `/` to come to root directory, I see everything again.

When I start my terminal:

```
~
```

if I type `ls`:

```
Code       Desktop    Downloads   Music      pdf       Public     Videos
Descargas  Documents  Escritorio  Pictures  Templates
```

If I type pwd:

```
/home/mynameuser
```

If I type from `~` :

```
~ cd /
```

I can see every directory and files:

```
bin      Documents       lib         Music     run       Templates  vmlinuz
boot     Downloads       lib64       opt       sbin      timeshift  vmlinuz.old
cdrom    etc             lost+found  Pictures  snap      tmp
core     home            media       proc      srv       usr
Desktop  initrd.img      mnt         Public    swapfile  var
dev      initrd.img.old  mssql-cli   root      sys       Videos
```

If I type from `/`:

```
/ cd home/mynameuser
```

I go to same `~` at beginning:

pwd =>

```
home/mynameuser
```

I think, I solve my own question after pLumo explanation.

When I start my terminal in my laptop, it opens inside `/home/mynameuser`.

When I start my ssh connection, It starts in `/root` directory, that it is not `/home directory`.

Comment: Where did you connect to?

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR:**

With `ls` you see the contents of the **current working dir**. You are probably inside `~`, not in `/`, that is why you cannot see `/home`.

---

The directory `home` is usually placed below `/`, the directory root. Running `ls /home` will show the content from anywhere, because path names starting with `/` are **absolute** paths.

When using `ls` you're searching for directories in your current working directory. Use `pwd` to reveal it. For a new `ssh` connection it is usually `~` (a.k.a. `/home/$USER/` == the users home directory) .

Use `ls /` to see `home` inside the directory root or `cd /` to change your current working directory to the directory root.